# How do you set the style of a textbox (html)

Tags: html, css

I want to change the width of this only:

```
     <input type="text" name="experience"/>
```

But I have got this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="2222" />
```

changing too.. when I set:

```
input {width:134px;}
```

Comment: You do not have a 'textbox.' Seriously. I realise it might be only me that gets frustrated with this, but what you *have* is a text-input. You might even have a `textarea`. But you *really* don't have a 'textbox.' Sigh...

Answer (score 1):

Give it a `class` or an `id` and use a class or id selector:

```
<input type="text" name="experience" id="experience" />
<input type="text" name="experience" class="experience" />

#experience { width:134px }
.experience { width:134px }
```

Alternatively, you could use an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

```
input[name='experience'] { width:134px }
```

Note however that attribute selectors do not work in IE6, so if you want to support that you'll have to go with a class or id selector.

Comment: damn, i have many textboxes... I have to do a lot of work then

Comment: Only if IE6 is important. If not, just use the attribute selector.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to apply only on a specific textbox, use [the `style` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_style.asp).

```
<input type="text" name="experience" style="width:134px"/>
```

If you want to apply it on all textboxes on the page, use the CSS:

```
.textbox { 
 width:134px; 
}
```

and then apply it on the text:

```
<input type="text" name="experience" class="textbox"/>
```

Comment: If you want to be mobile compliant, you shouldnt use inline styles, always use id selectors or class selectors. Thats what an integrator told me here at work.

Comment: Yes, that's true, hence gave the class alternate in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the HTML, you can set the css using the `name` attribute:

```
input[name="experience"]{
    width:134px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should give the input box a class/id ,
for example:

/

Then you should set the style parameters in your .css stylesheet:
In order to set class styliing use .name{...}, for id use #name{...}

Comment: You've got the `id` and `class` selectors the wrong way round. `id` selectors use the `#` and `class` selectors use the `.`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the style by type.

```
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="text" name="phone">

input[type="text"]{ background:#ff0000; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your orginal question mentioned a single text input, however your follow up comment mentions you have many text inputs, to avoid repetition in your css files, you could set the class of the input to something like "short" and then apply the width on that class.

```
input.short {width : 134px}
```

If you want to apply the width to inputs in a particular form (or element), you could use:

```
form input {width : 134px}
```

This may be more scalable in future if you need to change the widths of all text inputs for a form / site

Comment: That would select elements with the `short` class that are children of an `input`, not input elements with the `short` class.

Comment: James is right, your declaration should have been "intput.short" not "input[space].short"

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, actually James isn't quite correct as input elements shouldn't have child elements, as far as I'm aware, however it was an error on my part and I've changed it now - thanks